# ListView.DataSource looping data for React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I do a Console.log(this.state.dataSource) I get the image as below, I'm currently getting "Row goes here!"x 4 because the API return 4 results.

I tried to retrieve the user data like email but it wont "loop" and print accordingly.

I'm not exactly sure how this code works, comments would help abit.Please Advice

[image]

```
    var messagesTab = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => this.updateDataSource(res));
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
      })
    };
  },
  updateDataSource: function(data){
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
    })
  },
  renderRow: function (){
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Row goes here!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  },
  render: function(){
    console.log(this.state.dataSource);
    return (
      <View style={ styleseact.container }>
        <ListView dataSource={ this.state.dataSource } renderRow={ this.renderRow } />
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

[image]

I got this when I did a console.log(data); on renderRow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting your DataSource declaration. Split up the declaration and update.

**Declare this before `React.createClass`:**

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
  rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
});
```

**Remove it from `getInitialState`:**

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([])
  };
},
```

**And reference it in the update function:**

```
updateDataSource: function(data){
  this.setState({
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
  })
},
```

Comment: You can either check if `this.state.dataSource` is `null` in your render method, or initialize an empty `dataSource`. I've updated my answer (`getInitialState`)

Comment: Thanks! Anyway , How do i actually use the data? under renderRow?

Comment: Yes, the `renderRow` function you call has the specific data for that row in its first argument, so for example `renderRow: function (data) { return (<Text>{data.title}</Text>); }`

Comment: Hmm It's returning [Object, Object, Object, Object]
,GB
,7980321e17d5faaa04
,0.7 but I'm interested in looping the Object Object Object Object , it's actually the set of data that i'm suppose to loop. Please Advice?

Comment: I added how console.log(data) would look in an image on my question

Comment: In your `fetch` callback, you are putting the entire response in the datasource, maybe you should only insert what you need of the response. It seems like the first item in `res`, do you know what you are getting from the server?

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I see you are getting some data from a random data generator. The response is an object with, among others, `results` which I think you need. Use this: `.then(res => this.updateDataSource(res.results));`